# Open source tools to create quantized-mesh tiles for Cesium?

Tags: open-source-gis, tin, terrain, cesium

I'm looking for a tool or toolchain to generate [quantized-mesh-1.0](https://cesiumjs.org/data-and-assets/terrain/formats/quantized-mesh-1.0.html) tiles that can be used with Cesium. Possible formats for the terrain source are LAS, ASCII Grid or simple XYZ files.

As a first try, I've used the python library [quantized-mesh-tile](https://quantized-mesh-tile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to encode the tiles. This works quite well, but my problem is to create the TIN for the quantized-mesh tiles. Until now, my approaches didn't work or were far to slow.

Are there any open source tools available to generate a tiled TIN or maybe even quantized-mesh tiles directly?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121561/generating-a-mesh-from-dtm

Comment: @julsbreakdown quantized-mesh looks like some custom binary fromat rather that PLY. How to convert directly to quantized-mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My currently preferred solution is [Cesium Terrain Builder Docker](https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker). It is an extended version of the [Cesium Terrain Builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder) with support for **quantized-mesh-1.0** and can be easily run using Docker.

Processing steps are:

1. Reproject DEM tiles to EPSG:4326 (recommended), e.g. using `gdalwarp`
2. Create a Virtual Dataset (VRT) from the tiles using `gdalbuildvrt`
3. Create terrain files as described [here](https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker#create-cesium-terrain-files) using the VRT as input
4. Optional: Generate `layer.json` by using the `-l` flag

Answer (score 2):

Cesium supports two terrain formats:

1. **Quantized-Mesh**
2. **HeightMap**

For (**Quantized-Mesh**) you can try @juls comment.

But for (**HeightMap**) you can try this blog post:

[Creating 3D terrains with Cesium](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2014/10/3d-terrains-with-cesium.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Tin-Terrain](https://github.com/heremaps/tin-terrain) will do this. It is a simple open source command line tool that we have just released. It will generate a mesh from DEM files either as TIN or TRN or output tiles with zoom levels in quantised mesh format.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your tool works fine, but with a limited input size. For the whole extent, I had to merge the DEM tiles. The result was a very large heightmap (~60GB), which caused the tool to fail because of insufficient memory (16GB). Could this be solved by passing a GDAL VRT as input?