# Seeking inexpensive GIS software that can export TIN files to AutoCAD?

Tags: export, software-recommendations, 3d, tin

I'm an architect who would like to be able to download 3D terrain info and then bring it into AutoCAD 3D for use in renderings and animations using a couple of rendering/animation softwares called AccuRender and Lumion.

In the past, I was able to use an AutoCAD add-on software called EasySite (no longer available or supported) that could create TIN meshes from point files.

Is there an inexpensive way to download 3D terrain info that works in AutoCAD?

Comment: I think you should reformulate the question to target a well known format, otherwise it is to hard for people not familiar with autocad. For instanace, in [this conference paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289505340_QGIS_as_a_pre-and_post-processor_for_TELEMAC_mesh_generation_and_output_visualization) many options are presented for TELEMAC, does any one fits your needs? it is hard to know, probably no.

Comment: Have a look to this Q&A https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121561/generating-a-mesh-from-dtm. They also mention Meshlab, an open source system for processing and editing 3D triangular meshes

Comment: How expensive do you consider inexpensive to be?  For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.